# Which types of queues are in event loop?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I am faced with the mention of `render queue` in different articles ([example](https://blog.usejournal.com/welcoming-javascript-57e1051d9d), [example](https://medium.com/@atinders/how-to-make-your-javascript-app-less-sluggish-by-hacking-event-loop-dcbfd8afd88c))
Both authors say that

> render callback is given the highest priority

1. Is it true?
2. Does `render queue` exist as separate queue or is
   it alias for render callbacks?
3. Which callbacks are render? As I take in any repaint is render callback
4. Are there any other types of queues and if there are where can I read about them?

In [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html53-20181018/webappapis.html#task-queues) we can read

> tasks from different task sources may be placed in different task queues

But there is no mention about types or priority

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the HTML specs, the most important point being made about this matter is in the [task-source definition](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-source) where we can read:

> Per its source field, each task is defined as coming from a specific task source. For each event loop, every task source must be associated with a specific task queue.
>
> **`Note`**
>
> > Essentially, task sources are used within standards to separate logically-different types of tasks, which a user agent might wish to distinguish between. Task queues are used by user agents to coalesce task sources within a given event loop.
>
> **`Example`**
>
> > For example, a user agent could have one task queue for mouse and key events (to which the user interaction task source is associated), and another to which all other task sources are associated. Then, using the freedom granted in the initial step of the event loop processing model, it could give keyboard and mouse events preference over other tasks three-quarters of the time, keeping the interface responsive but not starving other task queues. Note that in this setup, the processing model still enforces that the user agent would never process events from any one task source out of order.

And in the [task queue definition](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue):

> An event loop has one or more task queues. A task queue is a set of tasks.

To summarize all this, the specs only require that every *event loop* has at least one *task queue*. They won't get into more specification about the *task queues*, but rather use *task sources*, that the user agents (UA) will link to whatever *task queue* they wish however they see fit, as long as the tasks in each *task source* are executed in order.

There are many *task sources* being used across the HTML specs, for instance [here is a list of the generic ones](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#generic-task-sources:task-source), but every specs can define there own, just like the [Message API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#port-message-queue), where each *MessagePort* object will have its own *task source*! (meaning UAs may map each of these message *tasks source* to different *task queues*).

Getting an extensive list of all the *task sources* is not really possible, and not really useful since they could actually all end up in the same and only *task queue*.

---

An other very important part of the specs we need to look at is the [event loop processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:event-loop).

This algorithm defines all the steps an event loop should go through at each iteration.
It's a bit complex at first sight, and it's not simplifying over time since more and more contexts are adhering to this model, with very different issues to deal with (*looking at you OffscreenCanvas in Worker...*).

But, for what we are interested in here, let's pretend it's simple and that we are in a Window context.

[The first step](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#step1) is kind of where the task prioritization is being designed by the specs:

> Let *taskQueue* be one of the event loop's task queues, chosen in an implementation-defined manner [...]

Just here, they say to UAs that they have the power to choose from which *task queue* to pick the next task from. This means that for example, if they have a dedicated *task queue* for the *user interaction task source*, and an other just for the *networking task source*, and that both contain tasks waiting, then they are free to choose whichever they prefer to run first.

Now regarding the *rendering*, if we look how the *processing model* goes after this task is executed, all microtasks are too and a bunch of measurements are made, we see that at *step 11*, they should [**update the rendering**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering). That's actually part of all event loop's iterations (in a Window context), but the first steps of this algorithm is to define if this was indeed a rendering frame or not, meaning that most of the time it will just early exit without doing anything.
When it is a rendering frame though, it has to perform all the rendering steps, as part of the event loop iteration, i.e maybe after a *normal* task has been executed.
So from the specs point of view, we can't really talk about prioritization here, it's just one part of every event loop iteration, just like the microtask checkpoint, it doesn't go back to the *step 1* where they can pick what task to execute, they are forced to execute that part of the event loop. <sub>*Though technically, in the rendering steps the UA is also the one responsible to determine when it has a "rendering opportunity", so if they want, they can actually set up that prioritization.*</sub>

So for us web-authors, that means that yes, we can have a `requestAnimationFrame` callback fire before a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` one (or any other task), at least in the case that the one task that did call this `requestAnimationFrame()` method was itself executed at the beginning of a *rendering frame*.

This may actually happen quite often, here is a small snippet that should make it happen in Firefox quite reliably, and sometimes in Chrome:

```js
/*
  In latest FF and Chrome browsers, UI events like mousemove are being throttled by the UA.
  (as recommended by the specs)
  They make the limit rate match the one of the screen-refresh, like resize or scroll events.
  However, at least in Firefox they don't make it part of the 'update the rendering' algorithm,
  but execute it as a normal task.
  So a 'mousemove' event in this browser actually gives us accesss to the first step of a 'rendering frame'.
  
  This simple snippet tries to demonstrate that,
  if successful, "rAF" should always be logged first.
*/
onmousemove = (evt) => {
  console.clear();
  setTimeout( () => console.log( 'timeout' ), 0 );
  requestAnimationFrame( () => console.log( 'rAF' ) );
};
```

```html
move your mouse over the frame
```

---

Now we can answer all your points:

> 1) render callback is given the highest priority.
>   Is it true?

As we just demonstrated, not really, even though it may happen render callbacks are executed in the same event-loop iteration as the task that did schedule them, we can't really talk about prioritization here.

> 2) Does render queue exist as separate queue or is it alias for render callbacks?

Specs, don't define any special *task queue*, but there is no *task source* for rendering either. The [*update the rendering*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) algorithm is made of a lot of different tasks to execute though, and in there lies the [*run the animation frame callbacks*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:run-the-animation-frame-callbacks-2) command, that you might be referring to. But these callbacks are stored in a Map, not in a queue.

> 3) Which callbacks are render? As I take in any repaint is render callback

It's all in [*update the rendering*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering), but you may want to focus on what comes after *step 5*, since before is just some checks.

> 4) Are there any other types of queues and if there are where can I read about them?

As already said, specs don't define *task queues*, and *task sources* are too loosely defined to give a complete list.

But remember that all this was from the point of view of the specs. Implementers may deviate from this model in many ways, and the model is itself loose enough to allow a whole bunch of different setups.

As an example, I'd like to point you to a [Firefox issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1270059), which introduces a very interesting case:
They wanted to have `setTimeout` callbacks have less priority than other tasks, **but only at page load**. For this, they did create a new task queue, just for this case.
And now, **in Firefox**, `setTimeout` callbacks have less priority than other tasks, but only at page load:

```js
function test() {
  setTimeout( () => console.log('timeout'));
  onmessage = (evt) => console.log('message');
  postMessage('', '*');
}
console.log('at page load');
test();

setTimeout( () => {
  console.log('after page load');
  test();
}, 1000 );

/* results in Firefox:
at page load
message
timeout
after page load
timeout
message

Chrome will always print "message" first, but because they have a 2ms min timeout on setTimeout
*/
```

And an other thing to keep in sight is the maybe incoming [Prioritized `postTask` API](https://github.com/WICG/main-thread-scheduling/blob/master/PrioritizedPostTask.md), with which we can already play in Chrome under the `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag, and which exposes a `scheduler.postTask(fn, priority)` method, which allows us to control the task prioritization.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) render callback is given the highest priority.
>   Is it true?

I think so from my reading of the link below.

> 2) Does render queue exist as separate queue or is it alias for render callbacks?

The link below says it is the same task queue, the "Event" task queue.

> 3) Which callbacks are render? As I take in any repaint is render callback

I think the render callback is basically the process of the browser periodically trying to repaint/render the screen based on the latest updates to the dom.

> 4) Are there any other types of queues and if there are where can I read about them?

Yes, see details here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue

This seems to be the best coverage of this: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops

Comment: 2) as I understood callbacks from one source go to same queue, but tasks from other source may go to different queues
4) No types only ```task sources```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is incorrect, unless I have misunderstood. This is my current source of information.

"Immediately after every macrotask, the engine executes all tasks from microtask queue, prior to running any other macrotasks or rendering or anything else."

https://javascript.info/event-loop

The below is an experiment which didn't behave in my code snippet, but it demonstrates that the microtrask from the `.then` inside `button_one()` take priority over the render change on the button. You can see from the console output of `"button one out"` that the microtask is after the button function.

```
<body>
    <button id="but_one" onclick='button_one()'>Click me</button>
    <button id="but_two" onclick='button_two()'>Reset</button>
</body>
<script>
    function button_one() {
        console.log("button one clicked")
        document.getElementById("but_one").innerText ='YouClickedMe';
        autoResolve().then(msg =>{
            console.log("Inside resolve callback")
            sleep(5000)
        });
        console.log("button one out")
    }

    function button_two() {
        document.getElementById("but_one").innerText = 'Click me';
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        const date = Date.now();
        let currentDate = null;
        do {
            currentDate = Date.now();
        } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
    }

    async function autoResolve() { return "resolved" }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no priority for the microtasks, they're just ran directly after the task that did queue them ends. The event loop doesn't loop.

Comment: Are you saying that even if the call stack hasn't been emptied the micro tasks can run?

Comment: No the call stack will be empty. It's just that there is a microtask checkpoint right after the 'Perform latest task", at current step 7 of the envent loop. So there is no  place for any priority system here, they're ran right after the task that did queue them, no other task can come in between. If you do `p = ()=> Pomise.then(p); p()`, the event loop will never spin again, the microtask queue will be executed indefinitely.

Comment: Okay so how is that different to permanent priority? Isnt the normal thing after finishing a task to look at what needs to be done next? Could you give me a specific example of what ordering this might change?

Comment: If you look at the first note [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model), you can see it's clearly noted that the *microtask queue is not a task queue.*, so your answer doesn't apply for the current question. For your question, if you keep looking at that same link, you'll see all the things that should happen in every event loop iteration. In my blocking promise example above, the event loop is locked at step 7 and never makes it past this point. The UI is locked, no more event can fire etc.

Comment: At step 1, the UA *can* choose from which task queue it will pick the next task to execute. A real life example is `setTimeout(()=>console.log('timeout',0);onmessage=e=>console.log("message");postMessage("","*");` Here, the timeout gets queued in the *timeout task source* (queue-A), while the message task is queued in the *message task source* (queue-B). And even though timeout was queued before, message will get executed first because its task queue has higher importance, but none of these will block the event loop if ran in a loop, the UI won't freeze, and other tasks will be able to run.