# How does the event loop in the browser deal with the event queue, job queue, render queue at the same time?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback, event-loop

Last week I started learning Javascript back-end with nodejs. While working with `async` functions, I wanted to understand this in all aspect and started doing research on this subject.
I found [Jake Archibald's presentation in jsconf](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0) and I tried to understand what an event loop is and how event loop runs in different queues and which queues can it handle.

I think one of the diagrams in this presentation is very good to understand all of the stuff.

[image: screenshot from linked video]

But I am wondering how the event loop handle job queues which consist of promise callbacks.
Can we add another route into this diagram for this queue?

[image: diagram showing 3 loops labeled "Event queue", "Render Queue" and "Microtask Queue", around a fourth unlabeled]. (I tried to implement it into the diagram :) )

And another question that I wonder is, what does the event loop do with the render queue?
Does the event loop send it into another place? Because we know that the event loop sends functions in the event queue or job queue to the call stack in the javascript engine to run these.
But the render queue has *request animation frame* and other style elements.
Is event the loop sending the request animation frame part to the javascript engine and send the other layout, style and paint part to layout engine?

Answer (score 6):

This diagram is an over-simplification of how the things work, to see in details what happens, I invite you to go directly to [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model), which have become actually quite readable and easily navigable these days.

From there you'll see that

> [t]he [*microtask-queue*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#definitions-3:microtask-queue) is not a task queue.

If we take the over-simplification road ourselves to explain the event loop routine with only what we're interested in,

- messages from other processes and previous tasks will queue new tasks in various [task-sources](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-source), themselves ending in fewer [task-queues](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue).  (This feeds the left loop of Jake's diagram).
- At each iteration, the first step of the event-loop is to pick the first task from one of these task-queues (chosen as they wish, this allows task prioritization).
- Every time the JavaScript call stack is empty, basically after every callback or script execution, a microtask checkpoint is performed as part of the [cleaning algo](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script).
- There is also one such checkpoint hardcoded after the main task has been executed (I think it's in case no JS has been ran during it, but a microtask got queued anyway).
- In parallel, the browser will listen for the monitor's SYNC pulse (which happens every 16.67ms on a 60Hz monitor), and when it receives one, it will queue a task to [update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) (right loop in Jake's diagram, used to be steps 11.6~11.15 in the specs, but has been recently moved in its own algo).
- During these steps it will execute a few actions like firing UI events, updating animations and run the animation frame callbacks. Every time one of these algorithm [invokes a callback](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#invoke-a-callback-function), the user-agent has to perform a new *microtask-checkpoint* as per the
  [clean up after running](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) algorithm, so for instance every animation frame callback will get interleaved with such a checkpoint, and [some](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations/#update-animations-and-send-events) of these algorithms even perform the microtask-checkpoint directly.

So this means that the *microtask-checkpoint* is not just executed in a single point in the event loop, it is executed once after the main task, and many times after each callback execution in the *update the rendering* steps.

The user-agent can not just delay the microtask, it has to execute it right after the task that queued it did complete, i.e, from the event loop perspective, microtasks are executed *synchronously*.

In the same way, the "render queue" used to not be a task-queue either, it had to run when the browser has a ["rendering opportunity"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#rendering-opportunity), and couldn't be part of the task prioritization mechanism ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627773/which-types-of-queues-are-in-event-loop/62188756#62188756)). Things have changed [recently](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/10007) in the specs so that it's actually called from a task, but we can still assume it doesn't participate in the prioritization system, or at least that it has the highest priority.

---

> Because we know that the event loop sends functions in the event queue or job queue to the call stack in the javascript engine to run these.

Not exactly. First remember that javascript execution is only a part of what the browser does, many tasks don't involve javascript at all, for instance, even if you do disable the javascript from your web-browser, the event loop still has to run, it still has to update the rendering, it still has to send forms, it still has to react to network events like the loading of a media etc.
What the event loop does is to run the task's steps, but these can be a lot of different things and they may not necessarily send anything anywhere.

Also, specs don't say at all how computation should be distributed, but regarding the rendering, we can assume that in a nutshell everything from [update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) until its 14th step should be done on the same process (it has to be ran sequentially), but the step 15 ("update the rendering"), which will actually *paint* everything to the monitor can be (and I think it is in all modern browsers) passed to an other process, dedicated to this rendering task.
You can check [Chromium's documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) explaining how they manage the inter-communication between the browser process and the renderer.

Comment: The specs have changed since this answer was written. Now the rendering is done as a task, and 'rendering task source' was added.  

Specs: _For each navigable that has a rendering opportunity, queue a global task on the rendering task source given navigable's active window to update the rendering._

Comment: @BlueGreenMagick thanks for the heads up, (I knew it changed since I did help review the specs changes, but I forgot about that answer). I'll amend, but note that it doesn't change much. Only the specs have been changed and no implementation has. We can still consider that there is no prioritization there.