# JSPDF Memory Issue

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Me and my team facing one issue of memory in our application. The issue is whenever we trigger jsPDF instance its works but after that it's holding lot of memory and we facing performance issue because its never release that memory after completion of task. For reference i prepare one example and you can check with that.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vkewvw?file=index.html

So in this example you see my memory footprint its some around 36 MB you can see on first screen shot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ptXS.png)

and after run the code its goes around 56MB and its not releasing the memory you see in the next screen shot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYUDD.png)

Can any one help on that how we overcome that problem we tried with iframe itself by not working properly.

Your help is appreciable for us.

Comment: The screenshots appear to be the same image (not url) and don't show anything about 36 or 56Mb.  The offsite test platform shows an error, `/~` does not exist, and from console messages may not work in Firefox. Please take the tour [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check help centre articles about [how to create a minimal reproducible example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and similar articles on the help center - the question currently risks being closed.

Comment: Having said that, the saveAs package used by jsPDF seems to wait 40 seconds before releasing a blob created for the PDF. Not sure if this accounts for the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi traktor,
40 seconds is big time for us as we have multiple blob generations sequentially could you please suggest any way to release that memory frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As raised in comment, altering the timing of revoking blob urls may improve memory handling in an application using `JSPDF`, but does not come with a guarantee to do so ...

---

**The Blob Store**

User agents maintain a [blob ULR store](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#url-model) that keeps a reference to Blob objects keyed by the urls for them returned from [`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). Holding a reference in the store stops the blob object from being garbage collected from memory even if JavaScript code has **not** kept a reference to the blob object itself.

The blob object can be removed from the URL store by calling [`URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL), after which the blob is eligible for garbage collection from memory provided no reference to it is reachable in JS.

Now `jsPDF` sets its global object to `window` in browsers' main JavaScript thread in [globalObject.js](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/src/libs/globalObject.js), and imports the global object as `_global` in [`FileSaver.js`](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/src/libs/FileSaver.js).

Lines 85 and 86 of `FileSaver.js` define the module's `saveAs` export as

```
var saveAs =
    _global.saveAs ||
    ... code for saving file
```

which implies you should be able to **shim the `saveAs` function** for experimental purposes by declaring a shim (using `function saveAs` or `window.saveAs =`) in file level script *before* including `jsPDF.js` in the HTML document.

Initially you could use the original `saveAs` code with console logs to demonstrate the shimming process works and that `jsPDF` still works. Things I would want to look at include

- is jsPDF synchronous - meaning does it only return to the caller *after* clicking the link in `saveAs` to save the PDF file produced?
- If it's potentially asynchronous, how to arrange a callback or promise resolution from the shim after clicking the link to prevent sequentially produced PDF files being processed in parallel.
- Does reducing the time before revoking the blob's URL, currently set to 40 seconds *for most browsers* in line 188 of `FileSave.js` (linked above), materially affect performance of the application?
- How well does the application run in Safari and ChromeIOS, which receive exceptional support in `FileSave.js`?

---

**Synchronous Revocation of Blob URLs**

There is some possibility that Blob URLs can be revoked synchronously after use. The following code (which doesn't work as a code snippet) creates a blob and downloads it:

```
function blobURL(string) {
    const blob = new Blob(Array.from(string));
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob);  // see NOTE 1
}
    
const url = blobURL("hello folks and world");
console.log("2 seconds...");
setTimeout( saveBlob, 2000, url); // see NOTE 2

function saveBlob(url) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute("download", "hello.txt");
    link.href= url;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url); // SEE NOTE 3
    console.log("Call to link.click() has returned");
}
```

Note

1. The script does not keep a reference to the blob created
2. Memory garbage collection could (in theory) run during a timeout period.
3. The blob's url is revoked synchronously, after `link.click()`, before returning to the event loop.

Calling `URL.revokeObjectURL()` immediately after programatially clicking the link to download the blob did not affect the success of downloading in Firefox or Edge/webkit when tested. This implies that these browsers **synchronously** obtains a reference to the Blob instance (using Blob Store lookup) **before** returning from `link.click()`.

This is consistent with the behavior of events programmatically dispatched on an element being processed synchronously (which I looked at recently in answer to ["Do events bubble in microtasks?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70735245/5217142)). How safe it is to make use of this in production, however, is not something I am personally in a position to guarantee across all browsers.